# Convert an image to ImageData (Uint8ClampedArray)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an image for example
"img/Myimage.jpg"
I would like to convert it to the Uint8ClampedArray format (as shown in the image). 
[image]

For what? I am using a library that after a long process converts the images to this format, but I have others images that I need to convert them on my own to this same format. how can I do it? Excuse my ignorance

```
var frames = animator.frames;
var res_c = document.getElementById("result");
var res_ctx = res_c.getContext('2d');
for (var x = 0; x < frames.length; x++) {
  //***frames are ImageData (Uint8ClampedArray)***
  res_ctx.putImageData(frames[x],0,0);
  console.log(frames[x])
  gif.addFrame(res_c,{copy:true,delay: 120});
}
```

I need convert my images in  ImageData (Uint8ClampedArray) for add others frames

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Image` constructor, `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`  and `CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()` to create an `ImageData` object from an image file.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const width = 300;
const height = 311;

const image = new Image;
image.src = /* Blob URL, "/path/to/image/served/with/cors/headers" */;
image.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 311);
  console.log(imageData);
}
```

Comment: great!  For that you used "const" ?, in this line I must put the route of my image? Image.src = "img / Myimage.jpg" ?

Comment: @yavg `var` can be substituted for `const`. Yes, the path to the image file should be set at `.src` property of `new Image` instance.

Comment: @guest271314 I am having this problem.. can you help me? https://jsfiddle.net/svvmrwvv/ my image is not in 300 x 311.. Does not fit the size

Comment: @guest271314 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378163/resize-image-within-canvas-when-generating-it

Comment: What will happen if the image size is not 300 * 311?

Answer (score 1):

An async/await solution using the canvas draw-extract method, takes one paramter as a source string (can pass `image.src` if you already have an image):

```js
/** @param {string} source */
async function imageDataFromSource (source) {
   const image = Object.assign(new Image(), { src: source });
   await new Promise(resolve => image.addEventListener('load', () => resolve()));
   const context = Object.assign(document.createElement('canvas'), {
      width: image.width,
      height: image.height
   }).getContext('2d');
   context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
   return context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}
```

Example:

```js
// image source
const source = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rovoska/undertale/master/sprites/images/spr_maincharad_3.png';

// async wrapper
async epic () {
   // log data to console
   console.log(await imageDataFromSource(source));
}

// do the epic
epic();
```