# Adjust image inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Resize image within canvas when generating it.

I'm trying to generate an image. From an image I convert it to a dataImage, and later I encode it to an image. and then put it inside a canvas element. The size of the width will be 300px and that of the height of 311px. But the image is not re-scaled. How can I do to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/svvmrwvv/

```
<canvas id="result" width="300" height="310"></canvas>
<br>
<div class='frames'></div>

var res_c = document.getElementById("result");
var res_ctx = res_c.getContext('2d');
var width = 300;
var height = 311;

//codifing image

var image = new Image;
image.src = 'http://tosemdinheiro.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/carro.jpg';
res_ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
imageData = res_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
console.log(imageData);

//decodifing image

var image_gif = new Image();
image_gif.src  = res_c.toDataURL("image/png");
image_gif.height=width;
console.log(image_gif)
image_gif.width=height;
$(".frames").append(image_gif);
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you not set `width` and `height` at rendered `<img>` element

Comment: @guest271314 But the image is not completely displayed

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, maybe I do not understand you.

Comment: Where do you use `load` event of `Image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the image to load before you can modify it. When you render it you must render it at the size you want. The `drawImage` function has several versions one of which is `ctx.drawImage(image,x,y,width,height)` which will draw the image at `x`,`y` and with a size as `width`,`height`.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("result");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = 300;
const height = 311;
const image = new Image;
image.src = 'http://tosemdinheiro.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/carro.jpg';
image.onload = function(){   // wait for the image to load
  ctx.canvas.width = width;  // set size
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,width,height);  // draw the image at size

  // Dont know why you are doing the following so removed it
  //const imageData = res_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

  // create new image
  const imageGif = new Image;
  imageGif.src  = canvas.toDataURL(); // "image/png" is the default mime type
  document.querySelector(".frames").appendChild(imageGif);
}
```